# How can I find max(balance) with account ID?

Tags: sql

I have this table and I need to print `max(balance)` with `Account_NO`, but I can't figure out how to get the result I want.

```
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
|  CUST_ID    | ACCOUNT_NO |BALANCE |STATUS|
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
| 6363251425  |     40     | 110000 |  A   |
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
| 6262521111  |     22     | 51000  |  D   |
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
| 1111254215  |     19     | 504211 |  A   |
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
| 6363251425  |     99     | 3620   |  A   |
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
| 9999999999  |     31     | 1000   |  A   |
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
| 6363251425  |     47     | 3000   |  D   |
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
| 9999999999  |     23     | 303333 |  D   |
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
| 1111254215  |     45     | 85424  |  A   |
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
| 9999999999  |     49     | 632555 |  A   |
+-------------+------------+--------+------+
```

so the result will be like that

```
+-----------------+------------+
|  MAX(BALANCE)   | ACCOUNT_NO |
+-----------------+------------+
|      632555     |     49     | 
+-----------------+------------+
```

How can I get this result?

Comment: You could order them by balance and select only the first row

Comment: Could you show what you've tried and where it's not working?  Also what flavor of SQL you're using.

Comment: @litelite What if there are 2 or 3 different account numbers with same balance?

Comment: @India.Rocket Yeah, didn't tought about that.

Answer (score 1):

You could join the table to itself using a subquery to get the `max(Balance)` and use that value to get the `Account_No`:

```
select t1.Balance, t1.Account_No
from <table> t1
inner join
(
  select max(Balance) as MaxBalance
  from <table>
) t2
  on t1.Balance = t2.MaxBalance
```

Here is a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/667477).  By using a subquery, you can use the aggregate function max() to get the highest balance and then join that back to the table to get the associated account.

Answer (score 0):

Getting maximum value from the inner query and then joining it back with the original table to get the corresponding account number will do the trick. In  case you have same max value for multiple accounts you will both accounts in you final output

Try this:-

```
Select a.ACCOUNT_NO, a.BALANCE AS MAX_BALANCE 
from
YOUR_TABLE_NAME a
inner join
(
Select max(BALANCE) as max_balance 
from
YOUR_TABLE_NAME
) b
on a.BALANCE=b.max_balance
```

My Output

```
ACCOUNT_NO   MAX_BALANCE
  49           632555
```

Let me know if you have any questions